# can't get props from child component in react

Tags: reactjs, children, react-props

I have a child component that has props passed to it when using the html drag drop api in a react component. I'm trying to log the child's 'type' prop to the console but I'm unable to access it using   card.type

if I log 'card' to the console I get the following:

```html
<div type="allowed2" id="item-2" class="card" draggable="true" style="display: none;">
  <p>card 2</p>
</div>
```

Here is my current code and my attempt to read the prop:

```js
const drop = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const card_id = e.dataTransfer.getData('item_id');
  const card = document.getElementById(card_id);

  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (i in props.allowedtypes){
    console.log(card);

    if (props.allowedtypes[i] !== card.type){ //need to check the card.type against my allowed types
      count++;
    }

    if (count === props.allowedtypes.length){
      alert('sorry that file type is not accepted');
      return;
    }

    i++;
  }

  e.target.appendChild(card);
}

const dragOver = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  return (
    <div id={props.id} onDrop={drop} onDragOver={dragOver} className = {props.className} allowedtypes={props.allowedTypes}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Maybe someone can shed some light on this? Maybe I'm not reading props correctly from react.children somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that logged to the console because using the function `document.getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement`, not a React component. React components do not actually exist in the DOM, instead they render to HTML elements. You can try doing this instead: `card.getAttribute('type')` to get the `type` prop of the resulting `div`